# Different comparing with CompareTo

Tags: java, comparison, comparator, compareto

I am trying to make a different comparison each time, depending on the situation.
For example:
I have a class called Line and in the class there is string name, int id and int extension
I want to be able to compare 2 different Line objects by their name OR id OR extension.

Comment: It's actually a good question even though they dont offer the code they tried (because there isn't much to try if you dont know).

Answer (score 3):

If you have two different comparing schemes, you'd probably need two different [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)s (or a single one that can be configured, e.g., by a constructor parameter on how to compare)

```
public class LineNameComparator implements Comparator<Line> {
    @Override
    public int compare (Line a, Line b) {
        return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
    }
}

public class LineIdComparator implements Comparator<Line> {
    @Override
    public int compare (Line a, Line b) {
        return a.getIf().compareTo(b.getId());
    }
}

public class LineExtensionComparator implements Comparator<Line> {
    @Override
    public int compare (Line a, Line b) {
        return a.getExtension().compareTo(b.getExtension());
    }
}
```

... and then use it according to your needs:

```
List<Line> list = ...

// Sort by name:
Collections.sort(list, new LineNameComparator());


// Sort by ID:
Collections.sort(list, new LineIdComparator());


// Sort by extension:
Collections.sort(list, new LineExtensionComparator());
```

Comment: This is great but I need to use compareTo, it's required.

Comment: Could we build helper compare methods as above, and then in compareTo randomly generate a number to use as the choice for which comparator? Its unclear if the programmer needs to be able to choose which comparison to use (although i realize that sounds backwards).

Comment: No it shouldnt be random. The user would ask how to compare. I think I got it figured out tho, I am still testing it still.